# Laravel Policies with Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

*Role* and *Permission* are two models and since they have many-to-many relationship, I have an intermediate table called `permission_role` table. But this doesn't have a Model. I am trying to attach a *Permission* to a *Role*. But `$this->authorize('create', RolePermission::class);` always fails with error `"This action is unauthorized."`

*Route*:

```
Route::post('/rolepermissions/{role}/addpermission', 'RolePermissionController@store')
       ->name('rolepermission.store');
```

*RolePermissionController*:

```
public function store(StoreRolePermission $request, Role $role)

{
    $this->authorize('create', RolePermission::class);

    ...
}
```

*RolePermissionPolicy*:

```
public function create(User $user)
{
    if (($user->usertype == 'ADMIN') || ($user->usertype == 'SUPERADMIN'))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is it because the intermediate table does not have an associated Model?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar scenario, and I'm doing:

`Auth:user()->can('create', RolePermission::class);`, instead of authorize.

I think (have not tested) you can also do:

`$this->authorize('create', [RolePermission::class, Auth::user()])`. The second argument in the array will get passed as the only param in your policy.

I'm very new to Laravel, I got some help to solve a similar issue, hope this works for you.